# Transfer weights of selected faces to an other bone possible?

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror

I forgot to apply mirror modifier to my model before I parented the rig to the mesh. 
I did that afterwards but it made occur some errors with the weight paint. 
 The screenshot shows my problem especially for the leg. It's weighted for the bone I crossed with red. The other leg is controlled by the very **same bone**. 
 The mirrored bone on the other side on the other hand doesn't have **any** weighted part on the mesh. 
 Is there any possibility to just transfer the selected faces (as visible in the screenshot) from one bone to an other of the rig? 
Or do I have to delete all vertex groups again and re-connect model and rig?

[image: Weight paint selection]

Comment: Ah I just figured out that I accidently named the bone .L instead of .R. That might be responsible for the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you named your bones, but each bone should have been assigned to a vertex group named as the bone. See the mesh "object data" properties tab, under "vertex groups". There you can select/deselect, assign/remove vertices from the selected vertex group.

You can control which vertex is in which group, and eventually remove wrong vertices from the wrong leg group and assign them to the right leg group.

Beware that weight painting can add painted vertices to the selected bone's group.

Marco

Comment: Thanks for your answer^^ 
I already found the panel for the vertex groups but have no idea how to change them. I so far only used weight painting when something went wrong but the result was always a bit... strange. There is a black arrow that lets pop up some more options. I am not sure what exactly to do now. I just know that removing them lets the bone have no influence anymore but not how to add/remove single faces from a group

Comment: Try to get the basics here https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html, then if still needed I'll explain more how it's done. I'm busy just now... sorry

Comment: Okay no problem, I'll try (=

Comment: Okay I see now what to do. The thing I'm confused about is the weight panel. Do all selected verts have weight 1.000 then or the weight they had before on the other group? I want to keep the amount of weight the way it is right now.